# Is it possible to hide certain content type options?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a module which creates a new content type attached to a Feed. For this content type having options such as "Comment settings" or "Revision information" makes no sense. Is there a way to hide those?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your logged in as admin (user 1), so you'll always see them, but for other users it depends on the permissions they have and you can also use http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options to toggle this for each role

Comment: I would like to hide it for everyone, including the admin user.

Comment: then you have to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the permissions on the fields/fieldsets

Comment: "I would like to hide it for everyone, including the admin user" why would you want to do that? you can make a siteadmin user and hide for him implementing hook_form_alter